# Passing an object to a Pipe instead of keys in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-pipe

I have a filter which accepts an object. Now in my html

```
<div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="subUserDetailsList">
      <table class="table table-striped" [mfData]="subUserDetailsList" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="5">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><input name="" type="checkbox" value=""></th>
            <th>
              <mfDefaultSorter by="name">Name</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th>
              <mfDefaultSorter by="email">Email</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th>
              <mfDefaultSorter by="age">Role Name</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            <th>
              <mfDefaultSorter by="city">Actions</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- <tr class="card-block" *ngFor="let subUser of mf.data | genericFilter: name"> -->               //This works when model of the above textbox is name. However my idea is to pass an object.
                <tr class="card-block" *ngFor="let subUser of (mf.data | genericFilter:filterArgs.first_name)">
            <td><input name="" type="checkbox" value="{{subUser.id}}"></td>
            <td>{{subUser.full_name}}</td>
            <td>{{subUser.email}}</td>
            <td>{{subUser.role.role_name}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{subUser.id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#role">Edit, Delete</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
```

Here is my Pipe's transform method

```
transform(list: any[], obj: {}) {       
    let result:any;
    let filter = obj ? obj : null;
    if (filter && Array.isArray(list)) {
        let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
        result= list.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((isExist, keyName) =>
                isExist && item[keyName].toString().indexOf(filter[keyName].toString()) !== -1, true                   
            )
        );
    }
    else {
        return list;
    }
    return result;
 }
}
```

Now my filter accepts an object. This never get hits to the pipe. Please suggest me. How should I pass an object from my html to a pipe.

Comment: With " This never get hits to the pipe" do you actually mean "never" or do you mean "only once" but not again when object properties are modified?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am new to this and my idea was basically to create a Generic filter and I tried like so. Plz suggest me if this doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

A small Example with regard to Pipes how to pass objects

**Template**

```
<div class="row gap">
        <div class="col l3 offset-l9 m4 offset-m8 s4 offset-s8">
            <input class = "browser-default" type="search" placeholder="Search" #input> // getting the input in a local variable and passing it to the filter
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col l4 m6 s12" *ngFor = "let competition of competitions | filterComp:input.value" (click) = "onSubmit(competition)">
          <div class="box">
              <p class="bigger"><b> {{competition.caption}}</b></p><hr>
              <p><b>League :</b> {{competition.league}}<br/>
              <b>Year :</b> {{competition.year}}<br/>
              <b>No of Teams :</b> {{competition.numberOfTeams}}<br/>
              <b>No of Games :</b> {{competition.numberOfGames}}<br/>
              <b>Current Match Day :</b> {{competition.currentMatchday}}<br/></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**PIPE**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterComp'
})
export class CompetitionFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, filter?: string): any {
    if (!filter) {
      return value;
    }else{
      return value.filter((data) => data.caption.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()));
    }   
  }
```

This Pipe filters the array taking in the value from the search box.

You can find this Live here [LINK](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/FootBallScores).

More on Pipes [LINK](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/pipes)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. You have to pass pass your filter object explicitly in the following way:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemsArray | yourFilterPipe: { 
  filterProperty1: yourFilterObj.filterProperty1, 
  filterProperty2: yourFilterObj.filterProperty2
}">
  <!-- display whatever you want-->
</div>
```

Otherwise the pipe does not update the specific properties you want to filter for. It's quite ugly, but worked for me.

Comment: If you make your pipe impure it should work out without this nasty object property rewrite.